# lightning:input time display

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightninginput

I am using a `<lightning:input type="time"/>` component and the picker is displayed to the user in 12 hour time with an AM/PM picker.

I want to display this value to the user in a table and the value is stored as a 24 hour string. Is there a component I can use to display this in 12 hour format, or do I need to parse out the time and manipulate it myself to display it in the 12 hour format?

Input:

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="6">
    <lightning:input type="time" label="Start Time" name="start" value="{!v.startTime}" required="true" aura:id="required"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="6">
    <lightning:input type="time" label="End Time" name="end" value="{!v.endTime}" required="true" aura:id="required"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <td class="slds-text-body_small">{!v.appointment.startTime}</td>
    <td class="slds-text-body_small">{!v.appointment.endTime}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such OOTB component (that I know of) to display the data as you want, and I have gone through a big chunk of the referenced components under the [Component Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref.htm).

That being said, you will have to create your own custom component to display the time selection as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The time picker to pick a time or provide an ISO8601 formatted time string in the value attribute, Please read doc of [time input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation). It gives 24h format time for example if you select **10:30 PM** output should be **22:30:00.000** **HH:MM:ss**.

For your case, you need to write logic that converts 24h to 12h to display time into the table, the following is the Js function.

```
 function tConvert (time) {
   // Check correct time format and split into components
   time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

    if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
      time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
      time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM
      time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
    }
    return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
  }
```

call this function like **tConvert('22:30:00')** you got output is **10:30:00PM**